# Linux VM unresponsive

Tags: linux

I have a Linux VM that became unresponsive in console. I knew it because ssh hangs and ping says no route to host.

I am not asking for the specific reason but what could have possibly caused this out of the various things it could be. Kdump is configured but it didn’t trigger (no GUI). Logging completely stopped during a certain time so /var/log/* does not give much information. Sar says memory and swap usage is high before logging stopped but it is a consistent usage of 90%+/40%+ for consecutive days. So I am doubting if its the cause. OOM killer didn’t trigger I believe because there is still swap space available.

Linux VM running in VMware with guest OS of SLES 15 SP1.

Comment: The question title is misleading if you are asking how to figure out why the VM became unresponsive as the original title implies you are trying to figure out an ssh problem.  Furthermore, there is no mention made of details regarding version or flavor of VM host, version of the linux operating system, etc.  Please augment the detail in this question to better facilitate getting an answer.

Comment: @kbulgrien I have made some modifications. Thank you for the inputs.

Comment: I'd still add version of VMware.  Also, did you try a login at the VM console vs. SSH?

Comment: @kbulgrien I don’t see the need of VMware version for this. This is just weird in a way that most hung systems I encountered before are responding to ping and this one do not. Of course, I mention it also that it is unresponsive in console. So can’t really do anything other than reset the VM then look at what logs available.

Comment: Could be an OOM situation. Please try installing and enabling `earlyoom` and see if it helps. You might need to configure it because from the look of it you're running on the edge of available resources. That's not a good idea.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov From my understanding, if its OOM - it should have triggered OOM killer but in this case it does not since there are still available swap (based on the last log by sar before becoming unresponsive). Besides, does OOM would cause hung? It would I supposed if I/O was high before it became unresponsive, but in this case it does not.

Comment: The kernel OOM killer is super unreliable and far too often it leaves the system unresponsive for hours and even days (!) before taking a corrective action. This has been discussed ad nauseam pretty much all over the internet for the past 20 years, e.g. see: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/cmg48b/lets_talk_about_the_elephant_in_the_room_the/ https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/8/4/15 A userspace process killer is required to fix the issue. The kernel developers have decided not to bother.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Ok, thanks so looks like my initial observation to doubt that resource utilization could have caused it is wrong. I was under the impression that it should have at least been both at 99% for it to be the reason. Last thing bothering me is why is it not responding to ping. Most of system hung I encountered before would have still responded.

Comment: If it doesn't respond to ping that could indicate a kernel crash which I've no idea how to debug.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov That is fine. Thank you for the inputs you’ve made.